# Google Script timing out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below code running twice daily to clean up some imported data from an API. I just need it to remove duplicate rows as the data is sometimes repetitive and it is very long. A big problem is that it will be collecting 4 columns of data over 2300 rows daily for a year, so it will be around 840,000 rows, and close to 4 million cells at some point. Already, with just about a week's worth of data, it is timing out. I originally had this as part of the main code (as you can see in the sample sheet), but I have moved it to its own function in the client's sheet now. Still, it is running far too long (last execution was 316 seconds, so very close to timing out). Any advice on how to speed this up?
Here is the code:

```
function removeDupes(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Imported Data');
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Trimmed Data');
  var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  dataSheet.clearContents();
  dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  dataSheet.hideSheet();
}
```

And this is my copy of the sheet (where the code is part of the "callAPI" function): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lyFa8goXC5zy_iY2U04E6bXbQz2aLSFd0z9b87l_gO4/edit?usp=sharing

I've already searched around for a while to find a faster duplicate removable code sample, but this one has been the best I've found, and still not fast enough.

Thanks!

Comment: When I saw your script in your shared Spreadsheet, the script in your question cannot be found in the script in the shared Spreadsheet. And in your script, it seems that `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Imported Data');` is not used. If your script in your question and/or the shared Spreadsheet are not correct for understanding your question, can you update them? If I misunderstood them, I apologize. By the way, in your goal, all columns values are required to be checked for the duplication?

Comment: I've updated the sheet now. Let me know if it still looks wrong. Thanks for catching the extra variable too, that was copied from the original formula by mistake. As for your last question, no, I only need to check columns A and B. If those are the same, the row should be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? When your shared Spreadsheet is used, the process time was about 1 second. But this was not useful for your actual situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to remove the duplicated rows by checking the columns "A" and "B" using Google Apps Script.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In order to achieve your goal, in this answer, I would like to propose to use the method of `removeDuplicates`. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function removeDupes() {
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getActive()
    .getSheetByName('Trimmed Data')
    .getDataRange()
    .removeDuplicates([1, 2]);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [removeDuplicates(columnsToCompare)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeDuplicates(Integer))

Comment: Will this delete both rows that have duplicates? Or just remove the extra row(s)? I need it to keep one of each of the duplicates, if that makes sense. I wasn't familiar with this function, and based on the link, it was a little unclear to me ;)

Comment: @Brian - RGY Studio Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my suggested script, when the same values of columns "A" and "B" are found, the 1st found row is left and after 2nd duplicated rows are removed. If this was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: This sounds perfect. I can't believe I never new about this function in SpreadsheetApp! I'll test now and if it works, I'll accept. Thank you!

Comment: @Brian - RGY Studio Thank you for replying. `removeDuplicates()` was added at July 2019. When my suggestion was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: I guess I need to keep myself better updated! This works beautifully. Down from 150-350 seconds to 40 seconds for the full script. The remove duplicates part is nearly instant. Thank you!